# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth showed No Bluetooth Found Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, devices

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04  for almost 2 months now I regularly have my Bluetooth speaker  connect to it every time but some how yesterday it I can not turn on my Bluetooth for a speaker but the mouse is still working fine. I check out with the command `hcitools dev` and it return nothing so I guess it cannot detect the Bluetooth devices. How can I've already look to many solution online but non of its solve my problem. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYeCu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7sx7.png)

Comment: Your mouse is not Bluetooth otherwise it couldn't possibly be working. If it requires a dongle then it obviously isn't Bluetooth, just some other wireless technology and irrelevant for the problem described.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I’ve edited it Thank you